# Run Chef's Knife from Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rvm, bundler, chef-infra

I have a rails web application that allows users to run automated tasks with multiple servers. I wired up a rake task to run every 5 minutes (whenever gem) and check for jobs that need to be executed and spin up the servers with the appropriate options.

My trouble is in actually running chef's knife command. I currently do:

```
sh %{bash -c -l 'cd ~/opscode/FTW && source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use system && knife rackspace server list'} do |ok, res|
  if ! ok
    puts "meh? (status = #{res.exitstatus})"
    puts res 
  end 
end
```

this gets me halfway there. It switches to the appropriate gemset (system's) without any trouble but on execution of knife i get the following:

```
Could not find multi_json-1.1.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I don't have bundler installed in the system gems... so I'm pretty confused. multi-json-1.1.0 is required by my web application. My installation of chef seems to require  multi_json 1.0.3 so there seems to be a mixup in the gem requirements.

the command runs from bash no problem... it only fails in rake at the knife part

any thoughts?

---

EDIT:
using mpapis suggestion i used the RVM gem and everything works great in IRB. I do the following

```
RVM.use! 'system'
env = RVM.current
env.shell_wrapper.run_command("cd /my/path/to/opscode/FTW && knife rackspace server list")
```

however when running the same code in rails console or from rake i have issues. Rails console essentially ignores my RVM.use! and rake blows up... does it have something to do with bundler interfering?

SOLUTION:
mpapis built a phenomenal gem https://github.com/mpapis/rvm-with that allows you to execute code within a particular ruby version.

```
RVM.with '1.8.7' do |r| 
  puts r.execute "unset RUBYOPT"
  puts r.execute "cd /home/hunter/opscode/FTW && knife rackspace server list"
  #puts r.execute "ruby --version"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: mpapis built a phenomenal gem https://github.com/mpapis/rvm-with that allows you to execute code within a particular ruby version.

```
RVM.with '1.8.7' do |r| 
  puts r.execute "unset RUBYOPT"
  puts r.execute "cd /home/hunter/opscode/FTW && knife rackspace server list"
  #puts r.execute "ruby --version"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you start the shell via 'sh' command bash will inherit the sh behavior and rvm will not be sourced properly.

sh was never supported by RVM but we had to disable it explicitly after problems with starting X server on Fedora 16.

Comment: What should I be using then? I tried using %x{}, system, and `` to execute the command. system gave the same error while `` and %x{} are equivalent and give:
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize': Could not find multi_json-1.1.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Comment: Is it not possible to execute rvm via rake? That would be rather unfortunate

Comment: there is gem for rvm-ruby integration => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-gem if it is missing some functionalists - you could fork and add it - or open issue so someone else can have a look on it later

Comment: thanks mpapis, thats exactly what i needed. Its making my life a lot easier. I used it in IRB and everything worked fine but when using it in rails c or rake i had issues. I'll update the issue with the details there

Answer (score 0):

The multi_json gem is actually required by fog, not Chef. The knife-rackspace plugin depends on fog, which brings in the multi_json gem.

The current version of fog (1.3.0) depends on multi_json ~> 1.0, so it won't be able to activate the gem using 1.1.0.

If you're set on using Rake for this, I suggest using a gemset for the knife-rackspace gems.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be an issue of not having the right dependencies. I already have knife working great with all the right gems. It seems to be a matter of a mixup of which dependencies are correct. I'm tempted to think its an rvm issue as mpapis pointed out that rvm never supported sh which might explain the issue