# Using Knife From Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, knife

We're using Amazon's SNS to notify our application of changes to our autoscaling groups. In the event a server's terminated, we want to delete the node.

The notifications are working fine, as are the auto scaling groups. The only problem I have is that I cannot run the knife command from within my Rails App, I guess because it's calling the wrong Ruby version and trying to use the Application's gems. We're using RVM installed ruby-2.0.0-p195 and I don't want to bundle Chef.

The error therefore when I try and execute knife is:

```
system "cd /chefroot/ && /usr/bin/knife"

/Users/SM/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': chef is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I can see knife's calling chef, but needs to do so as a system gem. In knife.rb:

```
load Gem.bin_path('chef', 'knife', version)
```

Have also seen [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878891/run-chefs-knife-from-rake) but I don't want to use the *rvm-with* gem.

I looked at the Opscode API instead but that's not really working for us. Is there a better, more sophisticated way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using ridley gem: https://github.com/RiotGames/ridley

Comment: That's looking ok. Will check it out tomorrow. Thx

Comment: This should do it, didn't really want another gem but it will save significant time.